# Coordinating a bathroom/bedroom update project...what's the order?

Tags: bathroom, bedroom

I am trying to plan my bathroom/bedroom update. I will be doing the following:
New luxury vinyl plank for both rooms (they are connecting).
Painting in both rooms.
New trim and doors both rooms.
Shiplap on one bedroom wall.
New granite counter top in the bathroom.
New tile on the outside/step in of shower.
New faucets.
Paint pocket door, vanity, and floor to ceiling cabinet.
New ceiling fan in bedroom.

Comment: The usual sequence is to install the fixed items first and in a top-down manner. I usually leave the painting to the last except the primer.

Answer (score 1):

If this was my project, this order:

New tile on the outside/step in of shower. (Can shift a little, but before LVP flooring.)

New ceiling fan in bedroom. (Any time before paint, as trade availability. Earlier is better, as electrical can sometimes be invasive and messy.)

New luxury vinyl plank for both rooms. (Make sure subsequent trades protect the new flooring really well.)

New trim and doors both rooms.
Shiplap on one bedroom wall.

New granite counter top in the bathroom.
New faucets. (bathroom stuff can be earlier as trade availability dictates. If granite is being templated, get that started early.)

Dead last: Painting in both rooms. Paint pocket door, vanity, and floor to ceiling cabinet.

Comment: Why paint last?,...having to mask off new trim, countertops, protect everything?  I remodeled a small rental (that I owned) a few years ago that involved replacing all the trim, doors, kitchen cabinets, flooring. After demo, patching areas on the walls, re-texturing, I primed and painted. Very easy since I didn't have to mask off anything. Yeah, I had to be more careful when installing doors, new windows, trim, flooring, but I think it was a lot easier, I figured if I damaged any walls, just patch and re-paint that part.

Comment: In a whole house remodel, I'd consider paint earlier in the process, especially when baseboard isn't being touched, for exactly the reasons given. In a small job like this, you have to do baseboard after floors, so floors are already getting protection for baseboard paint. Might as well do all the paint tasks at the same time.